# How to write a simple service with Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express?

Tags: visual-c++, service

I want to write a simple service with Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express so it could be called from a windows form written by c#. can any one help me?

Comment: no, people don't your task for free! try it your self, let us know where you got stuck.

Comment: You'll need to get two distinct processes that use different runtimes to talk to each other.  That requires a language-neutral process interop mechanism.  Using a socket or named pipe are the standard solutions.

Comment: Go to MSDN and search for "service sample". It lists several.